# sparse list of values using ranges

Tags: kotlin

is there a more terse way of writing

```
listOf('a'..'z','A'..'Z').flatMap { it }
```

The idea here is to iterate over some values in a range, like the numbers from 1 through 100, skipping 21 through 24

```
listOf(1..20, 25..100).flatMap { it }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can go slightly shorter for a list by using [`flatten()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/flatten.html) instead of [`flatMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/flat-map.html):

```kotlin
listOf('a'..'z','A'..'Z').flatten()
```

or a shorter form (from @Ilya) is to use the [`plus()` `+` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/plus.html) of [`Iterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/index.html) (*an interface that ranges implement*).  Each `+` will make a copy of the list:

```kotlin
val validLetters = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z')
val someNumbers = (1..20) + (25..100)
```

or go more lazy as a `Sequence` (not sure it matters here at all to be lazier):

```kotlin
sequenceOf('a'..'z','A'..'Z').flatten()
```

##As Helper Functions##

In Kotlin people typically create a helper function to wrap things like this up nicely; if you happen to re-use this code a lot:

```kotlin
// helper functions
fun sparseListOf(vararg ranges: CharRange): List<Char> = ranges.flatMap { it }       
fun sparseListOf(vararg ranges: IntRange): List<Int> = ranges.flatMap { it }
```

...and the usage for those helpers:

```kotlin
val validLetters = sparseListOf('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z')
val someNumbers = spareListOf(1..20, 25..100)
```

***NOTE:*** *the helper functions use `flatMap()` since there is no `flatten()` method or extension for `Array<out XYZ>` which is the type received from the `vararg`.  The lambda is inlined so likely there is no real difference in performance.*

Comment: For eager evaluation there is an even shorter option: `('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z')`

Comment: added that in an edit.  Works if you happen to have the ranges on hand, such as literal ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The `kotlin.Char.rangeTo` returns a `CharRange` that is an implementation of `CharProgression`. CharProgression is a subclass of `Iterable` and the plus operator is defined on iterables: `Iterable<T>.plus`

Yeilding a very simple looking and obvious

```
('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z')
```

Comment: If you have the ranges literally on hand, this is fine.  The `plus()` operator will make copies for each additional `+`.  @Ilya added this as a comment above already.